# How to show validation message in controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

How  can I use {ci_form_validation field='title' error='true'} in the controller ?

I have this code

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', $this->lang->line('title'), 'trim|required|min_length[3]|xss_clean');   
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fahad', $this->lang->line('blog'), 'trim|required|min_length[20]|xss_clean'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('writer', $this->lang->line('writer'), 'trim|required|alpha_dash|min_length[3]|xss_clean');
```

I want to print error message in controller because I am using jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this from user guide

```
echo form_error('field_name');
```

EDITED

ok try

```
echo validation_errors();
```

this will give you every error after that you can get what you want

Comment: i tryed but it showing no thing = empty 
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('full_name', $this->lang->line('password'), 'trim|required|min_length[3]|xss_clean');   
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fahad', $this->lang->line('blog'), 'trim|required|min_length[20]|xss_clean'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('writer', $this->lang->line('writer'), 'trim|required|alpha_dash|min_length[3]|xss_clean'); 

echo form_error('full_name');

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no way to do this with CodeIgniter out of the box. However, it is quite easy to extend the original form validation library.

- create a file titled "MY_Form_validation.php" in your application/libraries folder
- add the following code to application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php

  ```
  class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

      public function __construct() {

          parent::__construct();

      }

      /**
       * Return all validation errors
       *
       * @access  public
       * @return  array
       */
      function get_all_errors() {

          $error_array = array();

          if (count($this->_error_array) > 0) {

              foreach ($this->_error_array as $k => $v) {

                  $error_array[$k] = $v;

              }

              return $error_array;

          }

          return false;

      }


  }
  ```

Then from your controller:

```
    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($this->form_validation->get_all_errors());

    echo "</pre>";
```